# Как получить значение из объекта?

Tags: php

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#340 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(3) "USD"
  }
  [0]=>
  string(7) "11.1000"
}
```

Нужно вытянуть значение `string(7) "11.1000"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее простое обращение по ключу "0" должно работать.

```
$sVal = (string) $object[0];
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2867601